# flasgger /apidocs does not render with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, flask, swagger, flasgger

I have been using the flasgger extension for flask to render swagger UI for OpenAPI spec locally with developement server. But in production, when I throw nginx into the mix I am not able to get the /apidocs to render

Comment: Hi phoenix, please provide more details regarding the nginx configuration as well the flasgger one.